# Angular js 2 'node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. import Observable

Tags: angular

I am Getting below Error in Auth.d.ts file in Node_Modules Package.

[ts] Module 'node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
import Observable

Find the below code for Auth.d.ts file :

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FirebaseApp } from '../app/index';
export declare class AngularFireAuth {
    app: FirebaseApp;
    auth: firebase.auth.Auth;
    authState: Observable<firebase.User>;
    idToken: Observable<firebase.User>;
    constructor(app: FirebaseApp);
}
export declare function FirebaseAuthStateObservable(app: FirebaseApp): Observable<firebase.User>;
export declare function FirebaseIdTokenObservable(app: FirebaseApp): Observable<firebase.User>;
```

I installed  "npm install @reactivex/rxjs" this package also even then I am getting above error

Comment: I am getting the same error after I upgraded to angular 6 from angular 5. Did you upgrade rxjs?

Comment: Yup I updated RXJS

Answer (score 22):

Try changing it to:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Yes done with above line but still facing same issue

Comment: That did solve the issue I had, hoped that it will work for you too. Make sure you are getting the same error and not other one related to Of.

Comment: try using latest libraries, this works for angularjs 4.0

Answer (score 12):

Try `npm install rxjs-compat` or `yarn add rxjs-compat`.

It's works for me.

Comment: This is additional step required after the above step

Answer (score 6):

If you are using angular version 6 then You can use

// creation and utility methods

```
import { Observable, Subject, pipe } from 'rxjs';
```

// operators all come from `rxjs/operators`

```
import { map, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade 'rxjs' to use the current 'firebase' package.

The imports changed in new versions of 'rxjs', and firebase is compatible only with version 5.x.x of RxJs for now.

Change your package.json file to use a compatible version of rxjs:

```
"rxjs": "5.6.0-forward-compat.4"
```

and re-run npm install:

> npm i

Answer (score 0):

npm i rxjs-compat

Please add these in root folder

surely your issue will be resolve

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

and install

```
npm i rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 0):

if your angular version is 6 and above.

use below:

import { take, map } from "rxjs/operators";

import { timer } from "rxjs/observable/timer";

Install - npm install --save rxjs-compat

Also user pipe with other funtions(Take,Map).

timer(0, 10)
                .pipe(take(1000))
                .pipe(map(() => x));